# Can't retrieve the correct image size using javascript

Tags: javascript

Ok, first time posting a question so I hope I do everything by the book.

I wanted to use javascript to retrieve and display the width/height of an image that the user picks using an Input button. But it's a hot day here and I can feel my brain just going round in circles.

Using this script I get it to display the image and the width (or so I thought). I try to select an image which is 180px wide but my script returns the number 16. Other images either returns 16 or other arbitrary numbers.

EDIT: Different browsers return different numbers.

What am I displaying and what am I missing to get it right?

This is my HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Image size calculator</title>

    <!-- Normalize.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">

    <!-- Custom Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <!--[if IE]>
    <script 
    src="https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/blob/master/src/html5shiv.js">
    </script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Vilken storlek har min bild?</h1>
    <p><em>Supported formats are: BMP/CUR/GIF/ICO/JPEG/PNG/PSD/TIFF/WebP/SVG/DDS</em></p><br><br>
    <form>
        <input type="file" onchange="readURL(this);">
        <br><br>
        <img id="imageDisplay" src="#" />
        <label id="imageSize">Bilden är: </label>
    </form>

    <!-- How to load jQuery.
        1. Load the CDN version (internet)
        2. If fail, load the installed (local) -->
    <script
          src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"><\/script>');</script>

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
```

And this is the code in my script.js file:

```
function readURL(input) {


    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#imageDisplay')
            .attr('src', e.target.result)
            .width(this.width)
            .height(this.height);

    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);



    var imgWidth = $("#imageDisplay").width();
    $("#imageSize").append(imgWidth);
```

}

EDIT 2: Thanks for all the solutions. I tried out Scott's (which made me smack my forehead and say 'duh' when I read it). It seems I was on the right track as my suspicion was that the image wasn't fully loaded. I just couldn't get the code for checking that right. Sometimes you need a little push in the right direction. :)

Comment: Because this line `var imgWidth = $("#imageDisplay").width();` is called before the image had time to load. You need to use `onload`  for the image to be able to get it properly

Comment: use `URL.createObjectURL` instead of using the filereader and when u are done with the file revoke it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to get the size immediately after setting the `src` and it hasn't had enough time for the image to finish loading by then. You need to set up a `load` event handler for the image in addition to the one for the reader.

```
var imgWidth = null;
var imgHeight = null;

// The image needs a load callback that won't fire until the image
// is finished downloading.
$('#imageDisplay').on("load", function(){
   // Now, it's safe to get the width and height             > 
   imgWidth = this.width;
   imgHeight = this.height;
   $("#imageSize").append(imgWidth);
});

function readURL(input) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) {
    $('#imageDisplay').attr('src', e.target.result)
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`HTMLImageElement.naturalWidth`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_naturalwidth.asp) and [`HTMLImageElement.naturalHeight`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_naturalheight.asp) instead of just [`image.width`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_width.asp) and [`image.height`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_height.asp).

While the former returns the original/intrinsic width or height of the image, the latter will return the dimensions of the image as displayed. That means that if you are resizing it with CSS, you will get the values based on that.

Also, the image itself also has an [`image.onload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/image.onload) you should listen to in order to access its properties once it has finished loading. Otherwise, you might access them before and get incorrect values.

Anyway, `image.naturalWith` and `image.naturalHeight` are available before the `onload` event is triggered, so you might try to get them instead, but in order to have a reliable solution, you need to implement polling using [`WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

You can check this out in this example:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const image = document.getElementById('image');
const naturalSize = document.getElementById('naturalSize');
const displaySize = document.getElementById('displaySize');

let intervalID = null;

function updateSizeLabels() {
  naturalSize.innerText = `ORIGINAL SIZE: ${ image.naturalWidth } × ${ image.naturalHeight }`;
  displaySize.innerText = `DISPLAY SIZE: ${ image.width } × ${ image.height }`;
};

function changeImage(src) {
  console.clear();
  
  // Reset src so that you don't get the previus dimensions
  // if you load more than one image:
  image.src = '';
  image.src = src;

  // Solution with polling:
  // We try to get the dimensions just after setting src:
  const alreadyAvailable = pollNaturalDimensions();

  // Polling only needed if the dimensions are not there yet:
  if (!alreadyAvailable) {
    // Just in case we already have a setInterval running:
    clearInterval(intervalID);

    // Every 10ms, we check again if naturalWidth is there:
    intervalID = setInterval(pollNaturalDimensions, 10);
  }
}

function pollNaturalDimensions() {
  if (image.naturalWidth) {
    console.log('Dimensions already available.');
    
    // Stop polling:
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    
    // You can display the dimensions already:
    updateSizeLabels();
    
    return true;
  }
}

// Solution with onload:
// This will update the size labels everytime an image is loaded:
image.onload = () => {
  console.log('Image loaded.');

  updateSizeLabels();
};


input.onchange = () => {
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = (e) => changeImage(e.target.result);

  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}

button.onclick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
 changeImage(image.src === 'http://www.traversecityfilmfest.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Baby-driver-gif.gif' ? 'https://thumbs.gfycat.com/BleakTenderBarb-small.gif' : 'http://www.traversecityfilmfest.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Baby-driver-gif.gif');
};
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0 0 45px;
}

body,
input,
button {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 45px !important;
}

#image {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  margin: 16px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Select an image to see its dimensions:</h1>

<form>
  <input id="input" type="file">
  <button id="button">Load Remote Image</button>
</form>

<img id="image" />

<p id="naturalSize"></p>
<p id="displaySize"></p>
```

Note, that when working with local images, the `image.onload` solution might return the dimensions before the polling one. When testing it on my Mac, they seem to be head-to-head. However, if you try loading remote images, especially big ones and/or on slow networks, the polling solution would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest restructuring your code like so, so that your image loads before you set the width:

```
function readURL(input) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var imgWidth;

  reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('#imageDisplay')
      .attr('src', e.target.result)
      .width(this.width)
      .height(this.height);

      imgWidth = $("#imageDisplay").width();
  };

  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

  $("#imageSize").append(imgWidth);
}
```

Comment: I was trying to provide this advice, but in playing with a snippet realized this works unreliably. Likely due to a race situation where the image may or may not be loaded by the `.attr('src', e.target.result)` line before you fetch the width. I think Scott's solution is a better fit using the image's on load event.

Comment: I agree, Scott's solution looks more fleshed out

Answer (score 0):

As correctly pointed out by LGSon, you have to wait for onLoad.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onload = function (e) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = e.target.result;
    image.onload = function () {
        var height = this.height;
        var width = this.width;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){console.log(img.width,img.height)}
img.src = 'url'
```

Answer (score -1):

[clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientWidth) and [clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientheight) are DOM properties that show the current in-browser size of the inner dimensions of a DOM element, excluding margin and border. So this will get the actual dimensions of the visible image.

```
var img = document.getElementById( 'imageDisplay' );
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

If you are requesting image sizes you have to wait until they load or you will only get zeroes:

**Example:**

```js
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() { console.log(this.width + ' x ' + this.height ) }
img.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';
```

Comment: The question isn't what properties to use to get the data. The question is why the data isn't available at the time the code tries to get it.